# RestKit NSDictionary mapping NULL values

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, restkit

I have a mapped object which have this property:

```
@interface SynchObj : NSObject
   @property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *fields;
@end
```

mapped as

```
 mappingDict = @{ @"fields"       :@"fields",};
 responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SynchObj class]];
 [responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:mappingDict];
```

But when the server send a dictionary like this

```
{ 
  name:null
  surname:null
}
```

the mapping produces a dictionary with these values:

```
  name    : "<null>"
  surname : "<null>"
```

I would like to have "" instead of "". Is it possible?

Comment: Can you show the code for mapping?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use KVC validation which RestKit supports to verify / edit the value before it is set. If you implement `validateValue:forKey:error:` on your destination class (`SynchObj`) you can verify and edit the value being set for any key (you would need to iterate the keys and values of the dictionary).